# Subtract result of value from Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user, paidbook and settlement model. I want to subtract the count of paidbook from that of settlement within a given date range

**user model relationship**

```
  public function paidbook(){
    return $this->hasMany(paidbooks::class,'user_id','id')->select('user_id');
}
public function settlement(){
    return $this->hasMany(Settlement::class,'user_id','id')->select('user_id');
}
```

The below code gives the actual count from both settlement and paidbook model. However I want to be able to subtract **paidbook_count-settlement_count**

```
 return User::withCount(['settlement'=>function($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
                              $query->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date,$end_date]);
                           }])
                           ->withCount(['paidbook'=>function($query) use($start_date, $end_date){
                            $query->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date,$end_date]);
                         }])
```

Output of the above query

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
   "firstname": "ooko",
    "settlement_count": 1,
   "paidbook_count": 2
 }
]
```

Comment: What's the problem? You can loop all users get the difference. You have to be more specific about details of required solution.

Comment: Thanks. have thought of that I was thinking it could be done in the query

Comment: You could do that in query, but that would require `DB::raw()` statements.